# How to listen to multiple form fields on change in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Scenario**

My form has 8 fields but I want to listen changes on three form fields to apply same function to them.

I dont want to do this:

```
this.headerForm.get('start').valueChanges.subscribe(() => applyFunction());
this.headerForm.get('end').valueChanges.subscribe(() => applyFunction());
this.headerForm.get('middle').valueChanges.subscribe(() => applyFunction());
```

Im using this:

```
merge([
     this.headerForm.get('start').valueChanges,
     this.headerForm.get('end').valueChanges,
     this.headerForm.get('middle').valueChanges
]).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

But its not working, it shows me something like this when I start app, and when I make any change on any of those fields it doesnt show me nothing on console:

[image]

Comment: `this.headerForm.valueChanges`

Comment: I have 5 fields more, I just want to listen to those three

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a6sexy?file=src/app/app.component.ts , remove [] from your merge function

Comment: Thank you @enno.void, the solution was to remove [] from merge cuntion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

Remove [] from merge function.

```
merge(
     this.headerForm.get('start').valueChanges,
     this.headerForm.get('end').valueChanges,
     this.headerForm.get('middle').valueChanges
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Comment: the best answer ever , thanks